About race conditions when logging in using Oauth2
I'm resolving an issue with Oauth2 login where a race condition occurred while retrieving the token, causing the session's access token to expire. This is usually an unusual operation, but we still need to avoid it:
However, when logging in using Oauth2, we can only get the "code" but not any information about this code.
This means we cannot use mutex locks (different sessions, code with no information).
Here is our verification process:
User login contains code => use code to obtain token => use token to obtain user information and use user information as the corresponding key to store the token (access_token)
I'm wondering if there's a better way to accomplish it.
Edit:
When Oauth2 logs in (after the Oauth service provider logs in), it will be sent
?code=the-code to the server. If this step happens at the same time, "get access_token" will be requested twice. This way, the first access_token will expire and an error will appear.

So are you trying to avoid 2 processes that can't communicate from completing an authorization_code flow for the same user? It's a bit unclear what the actual race condition is.

The actual login process is not specified in OAuth 2 so maybe you are searching for a solution in the wrong direction?

When Oauth2 logs in (after the Oauth service provider logs in), it will be sent
?code=the-code to the server. If this step happens at the same time, "get access_token" will be requested twice. This way, the first access_token will expire and an error will appear.
